# Is the old, non image based flair actually going away, and if so, why?

Tags: discussion, flair

For a long(ish?) while now, [the flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin/flair) has said:

> What about the old, non image based flair?
>
> The earlier methods of sharing flair are deprecated and will go away
>   eventually. Please use the simpler image flair from this point onward!

Are there still serious plans to remove it?  I can understand the desire to have a simpler, image-based flair scheme, but why require it?  Is the old system a burden to maintain?

The old system gives me flexibility to not waste space on a generic gravatar image that I don't care about, allowing me to display everything in a nice, compact, horizontal row.  For example:

[image: Horizontal, gravatar-less flair example]

Comment: I find it amusing that you had to post that nice, compact horizontal row as an image.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Oh, I was well aware of the irony when I posted it. ;)

Comment: Can I assume from the lack of answers that there are no serious plans to remove it after all?

Comment: We shall find out. Hopefully we get a reply from the SE team, eh?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I think it's already gone.

Comment: @Manishearth even still, it'd be nice to see an official response on this.

Comment: @Manishearth: The old non-image based flair still works.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Have a link to one?

Comment: @Manishearth: http://www.taenarum.com/software/about.html

Comment: @jamesdlin: Interesting, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the description on the flair page is pretty clear: there's no development planned for this, it might break without warning and probably won't be fixed if doing so is more effort than removing it entirely.

As I understand it, the code to support this is fairly trivial right now, but that won't necessarily always be true and like all deprecated features you can continue to use it at your own risk.

If you're especially concerned about this, you could probably [write your own](https://stackapps.com/questions/2119/se-flair-html-combined-stack-exchange-site-flair) version. Of course, that could break too if you rely on profile-scraping - might want to use [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)...