# iframe flair broken

Tags: bug, flair

I know the "old, non image based flair" is deprecated<sup>1</sup>, but I still prefer it to the image-based flair (that doesn't scale well) and I'm sure there are still uses scattered around the web.

I noticed today that the `<iframe>` based flair is broken.  While the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/201952.html?theme=default) still works, the server is sending a `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header, which means browsers refuse to render the content.

This should be a super easy fix – can you *pretty please* remove the `X-Frame-Options` header from /users/flair/*.html?

<sup>1 - [Is the old, non image based flair actually going away?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132495/is-the-old-non-image-based-flair-actually-going-away-and-if-so-why)</sup>